# Array of Classes and assignment operator

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm New to C++, and I'm trying to do the following thing:

I have a simple class, called "sim". I want to create an array of 10 elements of type class "sim". So I've used `sim** a = new sim*[10]`.

Then I ran in a loop, and create new elements like `a[i]=new sim(i)`. But when I later try to print the values (fields) of each of the a[i]'s, I don't get what I except to.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sim{
private:
    int x;
    const int y;
public:
    sim();
    sim(int z);
    ~sim();
    void showInfo();
    sim& operator=(const sim& s);
};

sim::sim():y(10),x(0)
    {}

sim::sim(int z):y(10),x(z)
    {}

sim::~sim()
    {}

void sim::showInfo()
    {
    cout<<"x="<<x<<", y="<<y<<endl;
    }

sim& sim::operator=(const sim& s)
    {
    x=s.x;
    return *this;
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sim** a = new sim*[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]= new sim(i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        (*a)[i].showInfo();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the wrong output:

```
x=0, y=10
x=-33686019, y=-830047754
x=-33686019, y=-572662307
x=1869774733, y=201385040
x=725928, y=726248
x=1423328880, y=11
x=24, y=2
x=55, y=-33686019
x=4814584, y=-1
x=0, y=0
```

Y should be 10 always, and x should be 0-9.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with simply `sim arr[10];`?

Comment: Are you deliberately not using the `std` library?

Comment: Alex: Yes. this is homework, we are not allowed to use std library. jrok: I've tried that, with no luck. When I do sim arr[10], I can't use sim[i]=new sim(i).

Comment: @bomba6 That's because you're not supposed to. `sim arr[10]` creates an array with automatic storage of 10 sim's and *default initializes* them. `new` creates an objects dynmically and returns a *pointer* to it.

Comment: @jork: so how can I initialize const variables in this way?

Comment: Does it *need* to be const?

Comment: @jrok yes, it has too. HW requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of operations in your statement

```
(*a)[i].showInfo();
```

This is dereferencing a, giving you a point to a sim instance, then you are indexing into this. Instead, you should index into a, then dereference the result:

```
(*(a[i])).showInfo();
```

The parenthesis above are for clarity's sake. Given C++ operator precedence, you could safely write that line as:

```
(*a[i]).showInfo();
```

The reason for your bizarre output is that you are indexing off of the first sim instance you allocated with new, which is at some arbitrary location in heap memory. You are simply treating the subsequent chunks of memory as though they were sim instances, which leads to undefined member values.

Answer (score 2):

```
(*a)[i].showInfo();
```

This is not right. This will produce the same output as:

```
(*((*a) + i)).showInfo();
```

Which is quite clearly not what you want.

You are trying to access the `showInfo` method of the object stored at the address that the i-th value of `a` points to.

So you should write this:

```
(*(a[i])).showInfo();
```

And then you could add some syntactical sugar to that, so that you don't have that awful dereference operator:

```
a[i]->showInfo();
```

Comment: You shouldn't multiply by `sizeof(sim*)`.

Comment: @metal I thought that might be allowed, but I wasn't sure, so thanks for clarifying.